# Custom Linked List Iterator remove isn't working

Tags: java, list, iterator

I have a program where I need to create a custom linked list iterator for a linked list class I created. Everything works as expected but my remove method isn't working at all. Here is the source:

```
public class LinkedListIterator implements Iterator<T>{

    ListNode<T> current = head, previous = null;
    boolean canRemove = false;

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return current != null;
    }

    public T next() {
        if(hasNext()==false){
            throw new IllegalStateException("hasNext was false!");
        }
        canRemove = true;
        previous = current;
        current = current.getNext();
        return previous.getValue();
    }

    public void remove(){
        if(canRemove == true){
            previous.setNext(current.getNext());
            canRemove = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Define "isnt working". (To get that first line of code to format, i suspect you need an extra newline between your paragraph and your code)

Comment: Some notes not related to your problem: As per the documentation to `Iterator<E>`, `next` should throw `NoSuchElementException` when there is no next element.  `remove` should throw `IllegalStateException` if called before `next` was or if `remove` was called a second time before `next` was called again.

Comment: Your `hasNext` function doesn't seem to be right either...